# Solving equation with two equations for one paramter using constraints

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose I have a composite of functions: $ f(x,y)$ where $y=g(h)$, i.e.

$$f(x,g(h))$$

and $h\in K$ for a given subset $K$ of the reals. We know the form of the function $f$ and $g$, but want to solve the following problem for a given real number $p$: find a valid (maybe more than one) value of $x$ such that for given $p$ we have

$$p=f(x,g(h))$$
Let me make an example: $f(x,y):=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $g(h):=\exp{(-3 h+17)}$ where $h\in[0,103]$. For given $p:=1.3$ I would like to find a valid number $x$ and $h$ such that this equation is true. There are for sure restrictions such that a solution exists, is unique etc. What is the name of such a problem and how can it be solved numerically, let's say in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to notice that you only have either two equations in three unknowns: find $h,x,y$ such that
$$
   y = g( h ) \\
   p = f( x, y ).
$$
or one equation in two unknowns: find $h,x$ such that
$$
   p = f( x, g( h ) ).
$$
This means the problem is **under-determined** so it is not possible there is a unique solution.

In order to find a solution, let's look at your example: find $x,h \in [0,103]$ such that
$$
  1.3 = \sqrt{ x^2 + (\exp(-3 h + 17 )^2 }.
$$
One solution is
$$
  h = \frac{17}{3}, \qquad x = 1.3.
$$
I'm sure you can find many more.

One way to find more solutions is to rearrange the equation for $x$:
$$
  x = \pm \sqrt{ 1.3^2 - (\exp(-3 h + 17))^2 }.
$$
Since the right hand side makes sense for $h > ( 17 - \log 1.3 ) / 3$, this defines a whole family of solution.